# Projection Issues with QGIS 2.6.1

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I Started this yesterday and I was able to create the shapefile in QGIS but I need the projection to be in NAD 83 New Jersey State Plane (ft) Coordinate System, which I was able to change the layer into NAD83NJ.

The problem is the only base layer I found was the Google/Bing Satellite Imagery which is in WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator. How can I get the shapefile into NAD83NJ so I can see the shapefile has the correct coordinates?

This is in QGIS 2.6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to distinguish between **project** CRS and **layer** CRS.

If you use Google/Bing background, the **project** CRS **must** be set to EPSG:3857.

The other layers you add can have a different CRS. `On-the-fly-reprojection` will align these layers, even if they have a different projection than the background.

What you should not do is to use `Set CRS for Layer`. This will **not** reproject your coordinates, but will damage your data.

Comment: When i set up the shapefile i set it too NAD83NJ, so if i saved the shapefile will the shapefile open properly in the correct coordinates in some elses ARC of Qgis?

Comment: You can test it yourself by creating a new project in NJ projection, and adding your shapefile and other vector data for comparison. Take something from https://njgin.state.nj.us/NJ_NJGINExplorer/DataDownloads.jsp as reference.